# Rails remove column that has no data type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite

In my Rails 5 application I've accidentally created a column with no data type. Database is SQLite.

```
create_table "students", force: :cascade do |t|
 t.integer  "club_id"
 t.string   "email"
 t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
 t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
 t.string   "picture"
 t.integer  "payment_plan_id"
 t.         "activity"
 t.index ["club_id"], name: "index_students_on_club_id"
end
```

When I attempt `rails db:rollback` I get this error:

```
Rhys-MacBook-Pro:classmaster Rhys$ rails db:rollback == 20161011105423 AddActivitiesRefToStudents: reverting =======================
-- remove_column(:students, :activity, :reference)
rails aborted! StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled: undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass
```

I've tried running this migration:

```
class RemoveColumn < ActiveRecord::Migration
 def up
   execute "ALTER TABLE students DROP COLUMN activity";
 end
end
```

But I think SQLite doesn't support dropping columns. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: Instead of deleting the column try using `change_column` to set the datatype.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming it is the activity column you want to drop based on it not having a type in that file, if it is a different column then just change the column name below.

What you want to do is drop a column from the table, which you absolutely can do. In the command line do something like the line below (or exactly like the line below) to create the migration to drop the column.

```
rails g migration drop_activity_column_from_students
```

Then open that file, the method inside should be this.

```
def change
   remove_column :students, :activity
end
```

Then run

```
rake db:migrate
```

and you should see that one column get dropped from the table.

You can find a ton of information [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html) about migrations, if that is something you want to learn more about.

Comment: I've tried this but I still get the error message `undefined method 'to_sym' for nil:NilClass` when I tun the migration

Comment: Can you post the schema.rb file?

Comment: Try to add to this line `remove_column :students, :activity` a type of the column, for example `:string`, so the line would look like: `remove_column :students, :activity, :string`

Comment: Your `activity` column doesn't have type. That's why you can't remove the column.

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi I know the column has no type. That's my whole issue. Do you know how I can give the column a type or delete it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after trying various migrations and running `rails db:reset` without success, I just deleted my schema.rb file and ran `rails db:migrate`, which rebuilt my schema from scratch without the column that didn't have a data type. Just make sure that none of your migrations contain the addition of the "activity" column, so you don't repeat the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the type of the column by:

> rails g migration FixActivityTypeStudents

Then on the migration add this part.

```
    def change
        change_column :students, : activity,  :string
    end
```

Comment: I've tried this but I still get `NoMethodError: undefined method 'to_sym' for nil:NilClass` @Frank004

Comment: @Rhys0h maybe the error is on a method on your model. Do you have to_sym on activity on your model??  you can comment it and then run migration.